# Copy database from one mysql sever to another mysql server

Tags: mysql, database-design, mysqldump, database-recommendation

Following are the details of the database and server:

Server1:
Host Name: abc
Port Num: 01
database: test

Server2:
Host Name: xyz
Port Num 02
database: spareparts
userid: spts
password: abcdefgh@123

I have to copy all tables from database test to database spareparts.

Please guide me how I can copy them. I am new in using mysql. Also please let me know if any other details are required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several methods you can use such as

- mysqldump
- folder copy
- enterprise backup

for mysqldump use following command:

```
mysqldump -uuser -ppassword --database your_db_name --routines --triggers --events --lock-all-tables >outputfile.sql
```

and use following command at destination:

```
mysql -uroot -ppassword<outputfile.sql.
```

You can also use following method
  - stop server at source
  - stop server at destination
  - copy all the database folders from source to destination
  - start destination server
  - start source server

Hope it helps

Comment: What is -uuser -ppassword

Comment: it is format in which you provide username and password in mysql command line.